# Halachic Approaches to Utilitarianism vs. Deontology

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

Are there halachic sources that are relevant to the philosophical debate between utilitarianism (ends justify means) and deontology (ends DON'T justify means)? Al regel achas, the principle of Mitzvah Habah Ba'Aveirah being a bad thing might be a rayah to halachah preferring deontology. What do you think?

Comment: Pikuach nefesh might be a raaya the other way

Comment: I would guess halacha is probably most like Rule Utilitarianism.

Comment: @ArielK It would be a duplicate if this question were asking "can any ends justify all means?" but it is asking for sources on a larger debate over consequentialism and whether the results of our actions dictate the value/goodness of those actions.

Comment: There is a very interesting _midrash_ about a conversation between Yocheved and Amram about whether it is worth having children in a time of threat to the lives of male infants at the expense of possibly sentencing the same to death.

Comment: Ariel, The duplicate you cited is focused on if Judaism favors deontology. I'm asking for sources and counter-sources both ways. Double AA: explain. Are you referring to the concept of chassid shoteh (saving a drowning woman)?